# Prove that colliding celestial bodies produce perturbations in the fabric of space-time

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, curvature, perturbation-theory

So I was recently asked this question by one of my professors, it really is confusing for me at the moment since I only have a basic grasp of and the ideas Einstein proposed.

P.S: I was wondering if this connects to gravitational waves?

Comment: Yes, such collisions produce gravitational waves. What course were you taking when your professor asked you to prove this?

Comment: It wasn't a course, I bumped into him and asked for a challenging problem and he gave me this.

Comment: Well, to understand this you would need to learn about the following: tensors; the metric tensor; the curvature tensor; the energy-momentum tensor; Einstein’s field equations; how to linearize them to study small metric perturbations; using the linearization to derive something called the quadrupole formula for gravitational radiation.

Comment: You could try digging into Carroll’s *Spacetime and Geometry: An Introduction to General Relativity*. Do you already understand Special Relativity and Minkowski spacetime?

Comment: By the way, the celestial bodies don’t have to collide. They can just orbit each other and produce gravitational waves.

Comment: Another by-the-way: There is no *fabric*, just *geometry*. You’ll be learning about a kind of geometry called Riemannian geometry that generalizes Euclidean and Minkowskian geometry. It will be a grand adventure!

Comment: Oh wow, that's a list. Yes, I did study special relativity and Minkowski metric last semester, does that make things easier? Sure will look into the book. Riemannian geometry sounds interesting. Thanks, @G.Smith!

Comment: Yes, that makes things easier.